Are there terminal control sequences for selecting text?
Normally in the Gnome terminal the user can select text with the mouse to copy-paste it. However, once I enable mouse tracking (in any-event tracking mode with the \e[?1003h control sequence) this is no longer possible. While I can definitely keep track of selected text in my application and render it with highlighted colors, this wouldn't enable copy-pasting.
Is there a terminal control sequence I could use for notifying the terminal that a given portion of text is now selected and the user should be able to copy and middle-mouse paste it?

Most terminal emulators allow selecting text when shift is held even when mouse tracking is enabled. There is also OSC 52, which sets the clipboard directly.

As per the previous comment, you can manually select text by holding down Shift. Programatically setting the clipboard contents using the OSC 52 escape sequence is not supported by GNOME Terminal, though.
